# Android Studio conflict between actionbarsherlock and appcompat-v7

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, actionbarsherlock, android-appcompat

i'm beginning to work in an old application which was developped with eclipse and actionbarsherlock. I need to import it to android studio and i'm having some issues that i can't resolve. 
When i try to import some errors pop like this one

Error:(2) Attribute "titleTextStyle" has already been defined

I've read that this is because actionbarsherlock and appcompat-v7 have conflicts and a solution could be to remove appcompat-v7 but i don't know how. This is my build gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile files('libs/adobeMobileLibrary-4.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/AppMeasurement_Android.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar')
    compile files('libs/zbar.jar')
}
```

I see the appcompat-v7 in the external libraries but i don't know how to remove it.

Thank you so much for any help.

Comment: Try changing 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+' to 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'. The newer versions of the Play Services library also declare 'titleTextStyle'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+' to 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'. The newer versions of the Play Services library also declare 'titleTextStyle'. – FractalBob just now   edit